# Current status of Meteor for offline application

Tags: meteor

There are some threads on SO that cover this - but most of them are 12 months old. I want to understand if Meteor (and available packages) is currently capable of handling:

- An App that runs both online (when there is network connectivity) and offline (when there is not).
- Allows changes made while offline to be persisted to the server when online (and the reverse).
- Allows the data that is persisted to be stored encrypted on the device and only decrypted when used.
- Allows some attribute of the user (application password, or possibly a token generated by the server for each logon) to be used as part of the decryption key. (intent is that if the device is stolen and the screen lock bypassed the data is still "reasonably" safe).
- On both IOS and Android, rooted and not.

Comment: Do you mean can Meteor do this out-of-the-box? If so then no. But you can add a package, [GroundDB](https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db), which will allow you to do the offline bits and Meteor now has Cordova/Phonegap support for IOS and Android which allows you develop a native-ish app.

Comment: Not necessarily out of the box, no. The question is perhaps more "if I started tomorrow, with the core and available packages"...

Comment: I think its possible but you would have to roll your own encryption solution - there is a Meteor package of CryptoJS, although its relatively straight forward to add any JS library so if you had another solution it can be done.

Comment: GroundDB looks like the closest package to what you want right now. It doesn't have a good conflict resolution management though

Answer (score 8):

Quoting my own reply on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Meteor/comments/2jnagz/do_meteor_mobile_apps_work_offline/):

> when you export let's say an apk from Meteor, this is a self contained app? this app connects o a server? does it work offline by default?
>
> Yes, theoretically they will work offline. They do work offline now, but they cannot get new data from the server or execute remote procedures on the server w/o a connection (makes sense, right?).
> If you want a fully offline app, you can try to use one of the community packages for the offline data support: https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db